# cannot be resolved to a variable java 101

Tags: java

Newbie code for printing a matrix:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
public class Strings {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Strings String1 = new Strings();

        int alen =0 ,blen =0;
        String a,b;
        int [][] matrix = new int[alen+1][blen+1];


        System.out.println("Enter String a: ");
        Scanner usrip = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = usrip.next();
        System.out.println("Enter String b: ");
        b = usrip.next();
        System.out.println("Execute print method: ");
        String1.printMatrix();

    }//end of main

    public void printMatrix(){

        for(int i=0;i<alen+1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;i<blen+1;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            }
        }//end of printMatrix


    }// End class
```

Since alen , blen are declared in the class not in a mehtod I thought they were global varaibales. But looks like Its not what I think it is.

The error I get is `alen cannot be resolved into a variable` same for `blen` and `matrix` as well.

Same error when I try to access them like `String1.alen` as well.

Comment: Where do you see them declared in the class?

Comment: Line 6: `int alen =0 ,blen =0;`

Comment: What kind of block of code are those declaration in? What does the enclosing `{}` belong to?

Comment: Consider writing the `printMarix` method to take arguments.

Comment: belong to? 
They are in the main method. 
alen and blen will be calulcated based on user ip and I wanted to use them in more than one method. So what should I do if I want them to be used in more than one method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the  variables "alen" and "blen" you declared in main() are method-local, that means they are not accessible from printMatrix() method. Make them fields instead by writing:

```
private int alen;
private int blen;
```

just below the line `public class Strings {`

or pass them as arguments to printMatrix() method, as Christian suggested.

Comment: When pull the `alen blen` & `matrix` out of main and put them in class body the errors in `printmatrix()` method are gone but whereever `alen` & `blen` are used in main those lines error out saying <i>Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field alen</i>

Comment: Yes, sorry. You have to either declare those variables as static or use them from an instance method

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access `alen`, `blen` and `matrix` since they are not declared within the `printMatrix()` scope (you may want to read about scope in Java), here is one simple solution:

Pass the variables as arguments:

```
public void printMatrix(int alen, int blen, int[][] matrix){
    ...
}
```

and call in the `main` method:

```
String1.printMatrix(alen, blen, matrix);
```

Of course, that this is not necessary, you could just do:

```
public void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;i<matrix[i].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ugly, but for a beginner, you can do the following:

```
public class Strings {

    public int [][] matrix;


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Strings String1 = new Strings();

        int alen =0 ,blen =0;
        String a,b;
        String1  = new int[alen+1][blen+1];
        ...

    public void printMatrix(){

        for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;i<matrix[0].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            }
        }//end of printMatrix


    }// End class
```

Comment: So the variables we declare in main are limitted to main but cant be used in other methods ? If yes, in your code; `matrix` is a global variable since it is falling into the Strings class's body ?

Answer (score -1):

this is one way among many:

```
public void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;i<matrix[i].length;j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}//end of printMatrix`enter code here
```

call it like:

```
String1.printMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: -1 This answer does not contain an additional point which others have answered already.